# Remove the controller name in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have 2 views named "Index" and "Contact" in "Root" folder.I have done following Route in global.asax.`
Controller:rootController
View:Roor/index.cshtml,Roor/Contact.cshtml

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Contact",
               url: "root/Contact",
               defaults: new { controller = "Root", action = "Contact", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Root", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );

        }
```

When I run The URL is **http://localhost:8889/** is loading Index page.
but when i run for **http://localhost:8889/Contact** is getting 404 error. When I run localhost:8889/Root/Contact is successfully loading.
I want to run Contact without root in URL.

Comment: *Remove* the `Contact` route. It requests that `ContactController` should only be accessible through `root/Contact` The default root is enough to match controller names and controllers

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `root/` from your `Contact` route like following.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Contact",
    url: "Contact",
    defaults: new { controller = "Root", action = "Contact", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: Why not remove the route entirely?